# NetworkManager conection disconected reason -3 issue

Tags: linux, archlinux, networkmanager

Today suddenly i receive this issue - sometimes i cant conect to any network, some time i cant conect to WPA2 networks, by can conect to unsecure network, some times i conect to everithing. Before 3 weeks i haven any problem.
In logs by `journalctl -f | grep -i warn` i see:

```
янв 12 14:16:08 egor-pc NetworkManager[572]: <warn>  [1578831368.2657] device (wlp0s20f3): Deactivation failed: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.NotConnected: This interface is not connected
янв 12 14:16:08 egor-pc NetworkManager[572]: <warn>  [1578831368.2662] sup-iface[0x55cd805be930,wlp0s20f3]: assoc[0x55cd80652b80]: abort due to disconnect: Request cancelled
янв 12 14:16:12 egor-pc NetworkManager[572]: <warn>  [1578831372.0231] sup-iface[0x55cd805be930,wlp0s20f3]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
янв 12 14:17:18 egor-pc com.deepin.daemon.Accounts[683]: <warning> network.go:304: No such interface “org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties” on object at path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4
```

If need, i can send more logs, or check something else. I try use `sudo sh -c 'modprobe -r iwlwifi && modepobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1'` from UBUNTU forum but it now helps.
OS: Arch Linux x86_64
Kernel: 5.4.8-arch1-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing helps me https://linuxconfig.org/unmanaged-network-solution-on-debian-linux
Maybe ilt helps to somebody else